# CMD commands while note server is running

Tags: windows, node.js, command-line, cmd

how can i talk to windows CMD while my node server is running?

example:

> nodemon app.js
>
> cls <<< does not work

Comment: Open a new command line window.

Comment: .. Or `start nodemon app.js`. This opens node server on a new window.